# How to remove n-letter words from a string? In c#

Tags: c#, string

Please help, I don't quite understand how to write a task in code without using additional libraries.
Task: given a string containing several words separated by spaces.
It is necessary to remove words consisting of n letters from the string. The number n is set by the user.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Func(string text, string n)
        {
            string[] arr = text.Split(' ');
           
            text = text.Replace(text, n);
            return text;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of letters in the word: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the string: ");
            string text=Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"A string that does not contain a word with {n} letters");
            Console.WriteLine(Func(text,n));
        }
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you splitted the input string by spaces you got the array of strings. Every string contains `.Length` property, and you can filter out all the strings that do not match your required conditions. Then you just need to glue back the remaining strings with " " between them.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Func(string text, int n)
        {
            var filteredArray = text
                .Split(' ')
                .Where(x => x.Length != n);
            return string.Join(" ", filteredArray);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of letters in the word: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the string: ");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"A string that does not contain a word with {n} letters");
            Console.WriteLine(Func(text, n));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of letters in the word:
6

Enter the string:
Task: given a string containing several words separated by spaces
A string that does not contain a word with 6 letters
Task: given a containing several words separated by
```